# Move position of thumb with every chapter

Tags: formatting

I am writing my PhD thesis in LaTeX and would like to include a "tab" that shows the current chapter number in a gray rectangle on the outside edge of every page. This tab should move downwards every time a new chapter starts.

I successfully managed to include a tab (or thumb) using the code below but the tab remains in the same position. Any suggestions on how I can move the position of the tab every time a new chapter starts?

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%% packages for chapter thumbs
\usepackage{atveryend}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% add thumb
\usepackage[height={3.5cm},distance={5mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}%%%% <--- !

% for some blindtext
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}
\addthumb{\thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}%%%% <--- !

\chapter{Intro} \label{chap:1}
\lipsum[1-15]

\chapter{Continue} \label{chap:2}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Multiply the vertical distances by some constant times \thechapter ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The strange thing is that the documentation says that the thumbs move "downward as the chapter number (or whatever shall be marked by the thumb marks) increases", but there doesn't seem to be a way to make that automatically happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you need to call `\addthumb` for each new thumb.  I would recommend a newcommand:

```
\documentclass{book}

%% add thumb
\usepackage[height={3.5cm},distance={5mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}

% for some blindtext
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\thumbforchapter}{\addthumb{Chapter \thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Intro} \label{chap:1}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-15]

\chapter{Continue} \label{chap:2}\thumbforchapter
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem, :-).

Comment: Can we show this on just one page (the first page of chapter), rather than entire chapter?